# How many balls have a common color?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $B$ be a set of colored balls, its cardinality $|B|=4k, k \in \mathbb N$. Let $C$ be the set of colors, $|C|=|B|$. Each ball is painted in $k$ different colors from $C$. Let condition (F) be satisfied:

- (F): Any 2 balls have a common color.

Q: How many balls are guaranteed to have a common color?

I would like to get a lower estimate better than $|B|/4$, which is trivially satisfied without conditions (F) $\big(|B|/4=|B|\cdot k / |C|\big)$. Is it possible to guarantee at least $0.251 \cdot |B|$ for arbitrarily large $k$?

Comment: When you ask "how many balls are guaranteed to have a common color?" are you asking "what is the largest $n$ such that we are guaranteed to be able to pick $n$ balls that share a color"?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes. I think I was able to find a simple counterexample that gives exactly $|B|/4$ and is easily generalized to any $k$. Therefore, сondition (F) does not improve the result.

Answer (score 1):

I have built an example that shows that condition (F) does not improve the coefficient of 0.25. Below I give a block $8\times 32$ that can be copied an arbitrary number of times horizontally and vertically, getting a matrix of the required size, which will always satisfy condition (F). Matrix rows correspond to balls, columns to colors, used color is marked with $1$.

$
1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\\
1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\\
0\,1\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\\
0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,1\,1\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\\
0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,1\,1\,1\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\\
0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,1\,1\,0\,0\,1\,1\,0\,0\\
0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,1\,0\,1\,1\\
0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,1\,1\,1
$